# SQL Server Code not executing in parallel

Tags: sql, sql-server, parallel-processing

Which SQL functions exactly inhibit parallelism in SQL Server?  I ask because I am trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT  SUM(_dt7) AS _dt7, SUM(_dt8) AS _dt8, SUM(_FPRecCount) as _FPRecCount, _FPBucket 
FROM (
    SELECT _dt7,_dt8, 1 as _FPRecCount, (CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(_ID)) as INT) % 5)+1 AS _FPBucket 
    FROM [Example Database].[dbo].[_FP_Longer Test Data (Long)] 
    WHERE (1=1 AND (3=3 ) AND 2=2)
    ) AS q 
GROUP BY _FPBucket
```

but the execution plan never seems to want to do this in parallel, always serial.

I am wondering if the `CAST()`, `ABS()`, or `CHECKSUM()` functions are what are inhibiting it.

This article

http://web.archive.org/web/20180404164406/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx

and the document that it mentions

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/04/17/parallel-query-execution-presentation.aspx

both allude to the fact that 'Random intrinsic functions' inhibit parallelism, but it does not give the entire list.

Here is what the execution plan looks like:

[image: query execution plan]

Comment: What does parallelism mean to you and how are you noting that the code is not running parallel?

Comment: Comment out the functions one by one and see which precludes parallelism.

Comment: @mikemorris - added execution plan image.  there is no 'parallelism' node.

Comment: What do you expect to run simultaneously in this example?  from your first link:  "There are many things that prevent parallelism, either because they make no sense in a parallel plan..."

Comment: Could you specify the value of "Subtree cost" property of first operator from execution plan?

Comment: @JeffO the records are assigned a flag from 1-5 based on the hash of their ID.  Clearly this can be done in parallel.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean: The subtree costs, from left to right, are 0.673, 0.673, 0.673, 0.667, 0.538, 0.538

Comment: What is your cost threshold for parallelism? The default is 5 and that query is only 0.673. Parallelism is not free. It has an overhead.

Comment: @MartinSmith - its set at 5.  which cost does this refer to? the subtree cost?  Is there any harm at setting it to 0?

Comment: Most people consider 5 far too low and set it to something higher, like 50. How long does your query actually take to execute in serial mode? Do you get a paralle plan with `OPTION (RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 8649)`? How long does that take to execute?

Comment: @MartinSmith the query only takes 0.03 seconds, but my process executes a zillion similar queries so it adds up over time.  The whole process takes like 3 minutes, but CPU usage only averages around 10%.  I feel like the optimizer should be able to tell whether it will save time by executing in parallel.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MartinSmith.  Adding that option does not seem to affect the running time, and still isn't parallel...

Comment: I wouldn't expect parallelism to improve the running time tbh but it would be good to get a parallel plan to test this. What version of SQL Server? Does the execution plan XML contain NonParallelPlanReason

Comment: @MartinSmith: in fact, it does! `NonParallelPlanReason="NoParallelPlansInDesktopOrExpressEdition`.  Bingo!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the plan was not executing in parallel, from assistance from Martin Smith, is that

```
NonParallelPlanReason="NoParallelPlansInDesktopOrExpressEdition"
```

which can be found in the execution plan XML.